# apache2 not opening index.html (404 Not Found)

Tags: html, url, apache2, virtualhost, pi

I had several virtualhosts running with wordpress before. I uninstalled Wordpress to use my own website (HTML and CSS) but now I get an error "404 not found" saying "Not Found -
The requested URL was not found on this server." Can someone tell my why it is not opening the index.html file or where the problem could be found?

Here is my VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin jw.webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com

    DirectoryIndex index.html
    
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domaincom_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domaincom_access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Do you have any message in `/var/log/apache2/domaincom_error.log` that might explain the issue? The main items that I would look for are file permissions and the existence of an `index.html` file in the `/public` directory.

Comment: in the error log the following shows up:
`[Sun Feb 14 20:20:04.316486 2021] [php7:error] [pid 6266] [client number] script '/var/www/domain.com/public/index.php' not found or unable to stat`
but there is no newer log from the events today.